# Is it safe to use Webshim polyfills with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webshim

I need html5 features like native form validation ('required' attribute etc.) in older browsers as well, so I usually use this: http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/ However, now I must use ReactJS and I want to confirm is it safe to use polyfills with it? I don't really understand how they will affect the way React handles the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Polyfills that simply set or modify variables/properties are fine to use.  Examples of this would be the es5-polyfills, FileReader, FormData, XHR2, matchMedia, Promise, etc.

Some things like "HTML5 shiv and innershiv" manipulate html and will not work with React.  Also the Forms stuff and other similar modules won't work for the same reason.

---

A better option would be to do validation yourself; the html5 form validation is overrated, and tends to make your site look ugly and inconsistent across platforms.  I'd only use it in applications where appearance, full control, and very useful error messages don't matter (some internal applications).